# The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed for Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-server

I’m running a jupyter notebook on ubuntu server.  I’m trying run the selenium code below using chromedriver.  I’m getting the error below but if I run the line of code below in Ubuntu terminal it returns the output below.  Does anyone know what the issue might be?  I’m still pretty new to ubuntu.

Ubuntu code:

```
which google-chrome
```

output:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

jupyter notebook code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/home/username/chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bcd3289fe282> in <module>
     16 options.add_argument('headless') #downlod Chrome driver.exe
     17 #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/home/username/stuff/JobHuntCode/chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
---> 18 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/home/username/chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
     19 
     20 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

Update:

Update:

Ubuntu

code:

```
google-chrome --version
```

output:

```
Google Chrome 73.0.3683.103
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4c82dc01ab87> in <module>
     18 options.add_argument('headless') #downlod Chrome driver.exe
     19 #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/home/username/stuff/JobHuntCode/chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
---> 20 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/home/username/chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
     21 
     22 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

UPDATE:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

For some reason adding the lines above to my code solved the issue.  I found the code in the post below.

[unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error while executing Selenium UI test cases on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790733/unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-error-while-executing-selen)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=74.0.3729.6*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=74.0.3729.6*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

- Perhaps you are using the last GAed version of *Chrome Browser* i.e. **chrome=73.x**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6* and the *Chrome Browser v73.x*

### Solution

- Downgrade *ChromeDriver* to [ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v73*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on this.  I downloaded the version of chromedriver and now I'm getting the same error but with the new version of chrome driver.  I added an update to the original post with the error.  I also checked and the version of google-chrome I'm running is 73.0.3683.103.  (I've included that in the update also.)  Does that mean I have to get chrome-driver 73.0.3683.103?

Comment: I added some code I found in a related post that solved the issue.  I added an update with the code and link to the post.

Comment: @user3476463 I could have provided a bunch of other suggestions within the answer but I have tried to provide a canonical answer as per the error you are seeing as per your question. Glad to know your issue got resolved. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  Can you tell me what those three lines do?  "chrome_options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")"

Comment: @user3476463 Sir, I have provided all the explanation within my answer which you have linked within this question as in the form of `addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model` and `addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions`. Let me know if you need any further assistance.