# chrome failed to start: exited abnormally in docker container on macos

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

On my Mac, I built image with FROM selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.4.0-chromium in Dockerfile.

When I run my app in the container, I got:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.13 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'a45e0250acbf', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Image built in Jenkins with same Dockerfile run same application, it has no issue. Both chromedriver=2.29.461571.

I have setup remote debug and want to debug on my macos before I push to Jenkins/linux, but blocked by this chrome failed to start: exited abnormally in container on macos.

Why this happens on my macos but not in Jenkins/Linux and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.13 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'a45e0250acbf', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.29*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.29*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v56-58**

- Presumably you are using the latest *chrome=85.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v85.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 85**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.40* and the *Chrome Browser v85.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u252](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v85.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.87/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 85.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v85.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you for looking into. My chrome version is 58, it is supported by chromedriver=2.29. Note this set works in Jenkins but not my Mac container.Neverless

Comment: Build the latest selenium/node-chrome-debug, chrome version is 85 now but I got org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'b7da3083cde9', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_265'

Comment: Many people are having this issue, I have tried all suggestions, but still get same error. Here are my options:     options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=5005");

Comment: @gxu To address `unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` error see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790733/unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-error-while-executing-selen/50791503#50791503) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189108/tests-fail-immediately-with-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist/58192582#58192582) discussion.

Comment: I checked above, also added options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome"); the /usr/bin/google-chrome exists, still get same error