# Is Chromedriver_autoinstaller still working?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to run `chromedriver_autoinstaller`. I follow example here: https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

But I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

What does it mean? Is this package still working?

Comment: What version you are on ?

Comment: I guess the error is not complete in your post, could you please check it in order to have the full information that the error can provide?

Comment: @cruisepandey chromedriver-autoinstaller 0.3.1 , I use Ubuntu.

Comment: @SherlockBourne sorry, now I show the full traceback

Comment: I was referring to selenium version.

Comment: @cruisepandey selenium  3.141.0

Comment: AFAIK it should work with 3.141

Comment: @cruisepandey but it does not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

Execute your test as a regular user.

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)
- [unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error while executing Selenium UI test cases on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790733/unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-error-while-executing-selen/50791503#50791503)
- [Tests fail immediately with unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist when running Selenium grid through systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189108/tests-fail-immediately-with-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist/58192582#58192582)