# python selenium chrome driver 111 path is not handled

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
# code
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 111
Current browser version is 110.0.5481.100
```

```
$ /usr/local/bin/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995})
```

What's wrong?

Tested also with

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
```

Same error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two instances of *Chrome* installed in your machine.

The *Chrome* instance installed at the default location isn't used by your test framework. Your tests uses another instance of *Chrome* installation which isn't updated to recent **v110.0** levels.

Hence, though [chromedriver_autoinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423516/7429447) downloads and installs the latest [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) **v110.0** but there is mismatch between [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) version and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version. Hence you see the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to fix the issue. Now I get https://hastebin.skyra.pw/wefovafipe.pgsql