# Problems when running selenium with chromedriver_autoinstaller in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a following problem. I would like to run chromium on my Ubuntu using `chromedriver_autoinstaller`. My code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

But desired url `http://www.python.org` does not open, I just see `data:,` in the browser:

[image]

I tried to add some options, but it did not help:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/vojtam/Desktop/greads_scrape/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Do you know, what is the problem here?

I found this questions, but it did not help me:
[WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)

[unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error while executing Selenium UI test cases on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790733/unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-error-while-executing-selen/50791503#50791503)

[Tests fail immediately with unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist when running Selenium grid through systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189108/tests-fail-immediately-with-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist/58192582#58192582)

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: @DebanjanB See update

Comment: Why do you have to use `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage`, I can see you using user profile **vojtam**

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried this in the second example. Firstly, I use no options, as you can see in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Docker requires `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` when running chrome in selenium