# Chrome driver failing in Laravel Dusk - "Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 404 Not Found"

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, laravel-dusk

For the last day or so I've started seeing my Laravel Dusk tests fail on my CI/CD environment (GitHub Actions).

Suddenly, running the command that had been working fine all this time:

```
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --version | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "." -f1`
```

..fails with the error:

> file_get_contents(https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Trying to get around this by forcing version 114:

```
php artisan install:chrome-driver 114
```

...fails with the error:

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

How can I fix this and get my tests to start passing again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is [discussed upstream in detail here](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/issues/247) - in short, the 404 is caused by [Google changing the source URLs](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/) for the Chrome binaries from version 115 onwards.

Specifically for Laravel Dusk, this seems to have been fixed in this [Dusk issue here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/1040), so *theoretically* all that's needed to fix this properly is a `composer require laravel/dusk --with-all-dependencies`, but at least in my case, this would update a *lot* of dependencies and seems highly likely to break my application. I've asked on that issue what the best course of action is for a legacy Laravel application (Laravel 8 in my case), but in the meantime: **downgrading both the Chrome/Chromium browser and the Chrome driver to v114 should be a good enough workaround.**

This is easier said than done and it's taken me over a day to figure out how to do it successfully on GitHub Actions, but adding the following steps to your workflow file should be all that's needed to get the CI/CD pipeline running again:

```
  - name: Downgrade Chrome browser to v114
    uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@v1
    with:
      chrome-version: 1134343 # Last commit number for Chrome v114
    id: setup-chrome
  - run: sudo ln -fs ${{ steps.setup-chrome.outputs.chrome-path }} /usr/bin/google-chrome
  - name: Downgrade Chrome driver to v114
    run: php artisan dusk:chrome-driver `/usr/bin/google-chrome --version | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "." -f1`
```

Comment: Why not composer update laravel/dusk -W?

Comment: @Maksim `require` is better than `update` for single packages, but thanks for pointing out that I missed the actual package name.